# table does not have correct background color

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, quarto

I am trying to display a kableExtra table in a pdf document with BOTH striping and background color but the background color is not applied to all rows. It is only applied to the rows that have white striping. Rows with grey striping do not have the background color applied.

Any idea how to use both striping and the backgorund color so that all rows have the background color applied?   I am using kableExtra version 1.3.4,  rmarkdown version 2.17,  R version 4.2.2 and  RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin".

Thank you

Here is the .qmd file that you can run:

````
---
title: "Table"
format:
    pdf:
      toc: false
editor: source
---

```{r}
#| label: load-packages
#| include: false

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
```


# Table
```{r}

#| label: table
#| warning: false
#| echo: false
#| results: asis

t= head(cars)

# add background color to table column
t$dist = kableExtra::cell_spec( t$dist,  background = "red" ) 
kable(t, format="latex",escape=FALSE) %>% 
kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped"))  
```
````

I am expecting to see a table with all rows have the red background color applied.

Here is the current output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though "striped" has priority over cell colors.  If you want both, you're going to have to use `cell_spec` to set the color of every cell instead of relying on `kable_styling()` to handle striping.

Comment: That could get pretty complicated if you have many columns that need background coloring. In prior versions of kableextra both striping and background coloring could be used.

Comment: You can install an old version. They are available on CRAN at https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/kableExtra, and the `remotes::install_version()` function should be able to install them.

Comment: Version 1.1.0 appears to be the last version that behaves the way you want.